# Google Scripts - Dates/Spreadsheets/Automatic Emails

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

Apologies in advance - I am not a programmer. Just trying to piece together something for my business. Currently, I have a script that references a spreadsheet and sends out an automated email to my receptionist. This script provides all of the information I'd like it to but problem is that it sends out a separate email for every entry. Ideally, I would like to send a single email to my receptionist that contains a list of all of the appointments for the upcoming day.

### Issues I'm having include:

- I need to consolidate multiple emails into a single email containing a list of the upcoming appointments for the next day.
- I don't know how to select the rows I need because they are date values (DD/MM/YYYY). So I'm Looking for a way to read the date, recognize that it is one day before the appointment, and add these entries to a single list.

If anyone can help me out with this it would be greatly appreciated!

Here's what I have so far:

```
function receptionist() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 2;   // Number of rows to process
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 8)
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[2];
    var timeslot = sheet.getRange(i+2,7,1,1).getValues();
    var name = sheet.getRange(i+2,2,1,1).getValues();
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(sheet.getRange(i+2,6,1,1).getValue()),"EST", "E MMM dd, yyyy");
    var receptionist= name+" scheduled on "+date+" at "+timeslot;
    var subject = "Appt. List";
    var emailAddress = "receptionist@example.com";
    MailApp.sendEmail({emailAddress, subject, receptionist});
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You only want to process two rows?  `var numRows = 2;`  Or do you have more rows than that, and need to evaluate them all?  Where is the end of your `for` loop?  I don't see where it ends.

Comment: I'm trying to process about 1500 rows. NumRows was set to 2 just so I could test things without sending 1500 separate emails to myself. 

The for loop was taken out of an older code I've been adapting. I'm not sure what purpose it serves in my case so maybe it can be deleted but just hung onto it for safety sake.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this code, and it works:

```
function receptionist() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 2;   // Number of rows to process
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 8)
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var receptionist = "Today's Appointments \r\r";

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[2];
    var timeslot = sheet.getRange(i+2,7,1,1).getValue();
    var name = sheet.getRange(i+2,2,1,1).getValue();
    var dateData = sheet.getRange(i+2,6,1,1).getValue();

    var dayOfAppointment = dateData.getFullYear() + dateData.getMonth() + dateData.getDate();
    var todaysDate = new Date();
    var todaysDayNumber = todaysDate.getFullYear() + todaysDate.getMonth() + todaysDate.getDate();

    if (todaysDayNumber === dayOfAppointment) {
      var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),"EST", "E MMM dd, yyyy");
      var thisAppointment = name+" scheduled on "+date+" at "+timeslot + "\r";

      receptionist+=thisAppointment;
    };
  };

  var subject = "Appt. List";
  var emailAddress = "receptionist@example.com";
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, receptionist);
};
```

You do need a `for` loop.  I removed the curly braces from the `.sendEmail()` parameters.  Note the "\r" values to wrap each line to a new line.  This Line:

```
receptionist+=thisAppointment;
```

makes the `receptionist` variable longer by one appointment line on each iteration.  I didn't go through every line of code to determine whether the code is optimal or not.  The basics of what you need are there.  It may work "as is".